# UIView in landscape and portrait

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a UIScrollView with some views in it, everything looks fine in portrait. However when I rotate to landscape all the views are jammed up. Basically what I want is to keep the views in place but then I would be able to scroll on it up and down. How do I deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you support just portrait orientation like this

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
```

}

or you relayout your views by overriding this method

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

Answer (score 0):

if you've designed your view in Interface Builder, you should pay attention to the Autosizing options in the Size Inspector!
[Autosizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqJQc.png)